# IF conditional on String failing

Tags: python

I've been having a problem with a simple code i'm working on. It asks your name, and how your day was, and depending on your answer, it SHOULD do the action linked to that answer. Thank you for all help in advance.

```
import time
print "Hello."
time.sleep(.5)
print "What's your name?"
var = raw_input()
time.sleep(.3)
print "Hello", var
time.sleep(1)
print "How are you?"
i = 0
answer1 = False
answer2 = False
answer0 = False
repeat = True
while repeat == True:
        if i == 0:
                answer = raw_input()
        if answer == "Good" or "good":
                answer1 = True
        if answer == "Bad" or "bad":
                answer2 = True
        if answer is not "good" or "Good" or "ok" or "Ok" or "OK" or "Not so good" or "not so good" or "Not so good." or "not so good.":
                answer0 = True
        if answer2 == True:
                print "That sucks."
                time.sleep(1)
                print "Well that's end of my code", var
                time.sleep(1)
                print "See ya!"
                break
        if answer1 == True:
                print "That's awesome!"
                time.sleep(1)
                print "Well that's end of my code", var
                time.sleep(1)
                print "See ya!"
                break
        if answer0 == True:
                print "I'm sorry, I didn't understand you."
                time.sleep(1.5)
                print "Are you good, ok, or not so good?"
```

Comment: And what does the code actually do?

Comment: ... Should we guess as to what it **actually** does?

Comment: what does it print out if anything?

Comment: Please post **relevant** error messages verbatim, and take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: `if somestr == 'a' or 'b'` doesn't do what you think it does; this is `if (somestr == 'a') or 'b'`, and since 'b' is a nonempty string it evaluates as True as a bool, so the test as a whole is True.

Comment: @larsmans what it *does* is actually in the code, knowing what he actually **want** is more useful :P

Comment: @KurzedMetal: what the OP wants is described clearly enough. I'm just not going to run and debug the entire script.

Comment: Thank you for all who helped, especially deathApril (learned somthing new :D). I appreciated the fast responses. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 15):

these conditions will always be true, because **non-empty string literals are truthy** in python:

```
if answer == "Good" or "good":
if answer == "Bad" or "bad":
if answer is not "good" or "Good" or "ok" ...:
...
# is the same as
if (something == something_else) or (True) or (True) ... :`
```

so replate that code with:

```
if answer in ("Good", "good"):
if answer not in ("good", "Good", "ok", ...):
....
```

or better yet, if you want to include "GOOD" and other case variations:

```
if answer.lower() == "good":
if answer.lower() not in ("good", "ok", ...):
...
```

Comment: @JoeFish by your definition of "good answer" we should rewrite all of his code completely because it's a complete mess, but it would be off-topic for the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
if answer == "Bad" or "bad":
```

you probably meant:

```
if answer == "Bad" or answer == "bad":
```

or

```
if answer in ("Bad", "bad"):
```

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, you should be more specific about what is wrong, but the following line surely is:

```
if answer is not "good" or "Good" or "ok" or "Ok" or "OK" or "Not so good" or "not so good" or "Not so good." or "not so good."
```

This should look like e.g.

```
if answer not in ('good', 'Good', ...):
```

Also, you might find `else` clause useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

replace your condition with these ones.

```
if i == 0:
        answer = raw_input().strip() #use strip(), because command prompt adds a \n after you hit enter
        if answer == ("Good") or answer ==("good"):
                answer1 = True
        if answer == "Bad" or answer =="bad":
                answer2 = True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use logical operators, always keep in mind that you need to have boolean values as operands as well.

Meaning, in your code

```
if answer == "Good" or "good":
```

You are trying to compare, `answer == "Good"`, which yields a boolean value, and `"good"`, which is basically a string literal.

To fix that, you need to rewrite your conditions

```
if answer == "Good" or answer == "good":
```